# How to create different bullet points with xml in word with apache poi in java?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, apache-poi

I am generating a word document in java witht he help of the apache poi library.

Currently I have square bullet points that are bit bigger in size. I want round bullet points filled in smaller size. I have done the following that is generating a square black filled bullet points -

```
"<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF06E\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u2013\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u26Ac\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the xml for the rounded filled bullet points

```
 "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\" >" +
        "<w:nsid w:val=\"34362CFE\"/>" +
        "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/><w:tmpl w:val=\"B16CFB68\"/>" +
        "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\" w:tplc=\"04070001\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/>" +
        "<w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0B7\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/>" +
        "<w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Symbol\" w:hAnsi=\"Symbol\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr>" +
        "</w:lvl><w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tplc=\"04070003\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"o\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/>" +
        "</w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>" +
        "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tplc=\"04070005\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0A7\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr>" +
        "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>" +
        "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"3\" w:tplc=\"04070001\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0B7\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2880\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr>" +
        "<w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Symbol\" w:hAnsi=\"Symbol\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl><w:lvl w:ilvl=\"4\" w:tplc=\"04070003\" w:tentative=\"1\">" +
        "<w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"o\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr>" +
        "<w:ind w:left=\"3600\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr>" +
        "<w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>" +
        "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"5\" w:tplc=\"04070005\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0A7\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"4320\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr>" +
        "<w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>" +
        "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"6\" w:tplc=\"04070001\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0B7\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"5040\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr>" +
        "<w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Symbol\" w:hAnsi=\"Symbol\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl><w:lvl w:ilvl=\"7\" w:tplc=\"04070003\" w:tentative=\"1\">" +
        "<w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"o\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr>" +
        "<w:ind w:left=\"5760\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/>" +
        "</w:rPr></w:lvl><w:lvl w:ilvl=\"8\" w:tplc=\"04070005\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0A7\"/>" +
        "<w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"6480\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr>" +
        "<w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Wingdings\" w:hAnsi=\"Wingdings\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>\n" +
        "</w:abstractNum>";
```